# php server-to-server post?

Tags: php, curl

I'd like to have one server make an http post request to another server.  Can I do this with a basic php install (Dreamhost in my case)? If so, please point me in the right direction! 
thanks,
-Morgan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd [use Curl](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html), if I were you.

Edit: And it looks like [it's supported on DH](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/CURL).

Comment: I'd also recommend Curl, especially of you need to pass lots of parameters etc. It is also worth remembering that most of PHP's file functions will happily open URL's as well as local files.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.brezovsky.net/en-text-3.html

```
    function httpSocketConnection($host, $method, $path, $data)
    {
        global $Db;


        $method = strtoupper($method);        

        if ($method == "GET")
        {
            $path.= '?'.$data;
        }    

        $filePointer = fsockopen($host, 80, $errorNumber, $errorString);

        if (!$filePointer) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Chyba spojeni $errorNumber $errorString");
        }

        $requestHeader = $method." ".$path."  HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $requestHeader.= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
        $requestHeader.= "User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0\r\n";
        $requestHeader.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";

        if ($method == "POST")
        {
            $requestHeader.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
        }

        $requestHeader.= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        if ($method == "POST")
        {
            $requestHeader.= $data;
        }            

        fwrite($filePointer, $requestHeader);

        $responseHeader = '';
        $responseContent = '';

        do 
        {
            $responseHeader.= fread($filePointer, 1); 
        }
        while (!preg_match('/\\r\\n\\r\\n$/', $responseHeader));


        if (!strstr($responseHeader, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"))
        {
            while (!feof($filePointer))
            {
                $responseContent.= fgets($filePointer, 128);
            }
        }
        else 
        {

            while ($chunk_length = hexdec(fgets($filePointer))) 
            {
                $responseContentChunk = '';


                $read_length = 0;

                while ($read_length < $chunk_length) 
                {
                    $responseContentChunk .= fread($filePointer, $chunk_length - $read_length);
                    $read_length = strlen($responseContentChunk);
                }

                $responseContent.= $responseContentChunk;

                fgets($filePointer);

            }

        }




        return chop($responseContent);

    }
```

Comment: None of the standard php stream-reading/writing commands have URL access on Dreamhost (AFAIK) for security reasons.

Comment: Using the http stream wrapper would seem a lot more sensible if that stuff was enabled, anyhow.