# PHP - Add form element before submit - Buy Button

Tags: php, jquery, forms, form-submit, hidden-field

I need to dynamically add form elements to an HTML form as soon as the Submit button is clicked but before the POST data is sent to a server. The new elements must be "read" from a PHP file on my server.

HISTORY:
Currently my HTML form has "hidden" fields that are submitted to another server for processing. I have no control over the other server. My problem is that anyone can edit these hidden fields.

How can I dynamically add form elements to the POST data as soon as the form is submitted?

Comment: Anyone can submit a form with whatever data in your behalf, so I don't understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish here ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way:

1. First disable the submit by changing the submit button type from 'submit' to 'button' (or whatever)
2. Put in `onclick` on that button to a javascript routine (here i use `submit_form()`).
3. Create an empty div within your form. (here i call it with `id = 'dynamic'`)
4. Using jquery, this is the `submit_form()`.
5. I think you will need to give it some time for these elements to bind properly before submitting. Maybe a short time delay before `$("#myForm").submit()`;

Here is the code for the `submit_form()` function:

```
function submit_form()
  {
    $("#dynamic").append("<input type='hidden' name='input1' value='whatever'>");
    $("#dynamic").append("<input type='hidden' name='input2' value='whatever'>");
    $("#myForm").submit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post the data to your server and after it post again to the external server with the new elements attached.

Your job is done on server side.

See also:

[php server-to-server post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457874/php-server-to-server-post)

Answer (score 0):

If you need any control over what is submitted to the other server, you have to do that yourself. Make the form submit to your own server, then validate it, add your data and re-submit it to the other server.

You can use the CURL extension in PHP to post data from your server.